# Comparing directories

Tags: windows, file-transfer, file-management, comparison, file-comparison

At some point when there was a software upgrade the previous support person that I took over from made a copy of a directory to the new server for the upgrade. We've kept the old server around apparently and are now looking to decommission it.

The end users are concerned with outright deleting the data on the old server for fear that the new server doesn't have a direct copy. Since the previous support person is unavailable and since we need to be 100% sure everything was retained, for legal compliance, it's falling on me to determine how to do it.

There are a couple of gotchas:

1) The new server's directory has been having new files put into the directory since it's went "live".

2) The files on the new server may have moved into different sub directories than where they originally existed on the old server. This may or may not have caused the timestamps to get updated.

My biggest concern is getting at least a list of files that exist in the "old" directory that do not exist in the new directory. I don't necessarily care that files exist on the new server don't exist on the old server.

Is there a tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

RoboCopy (built in to Windows) is your friend here.

```
robocopy [path to old server directory] [path to new server directory] /mir /l
```

`/mir` indicates that you want to mirror the old server's directory into the new server's directory

`/l` just lists the files that would be copied, without actually copying them

If the number of files and directories is large, you may want to log the output to a file for easier viewing.

```
/log:C:\logfile.txt
```

Robocopy will report any files or directories on the old server but not on the new server as New File or New Dir.  Files on the new server that are not on the old server will be reported as Extra.

As always, you can run `robocopy /?` for additional options.

### **Warning: You probably do not want to use the `/mir` option when you actually sync your data, as you will lose files that are on the new server but not on the old server.**